# Verificar se existe sessão preenchida

Tags: php, session

Eu estou tendo problemas para verificar se existe algo dentro da sessão.
As funções que estou utlizando são:
   Função para verificar se tem alguém logado

```
if(usuarioestalogado()){?>
<p class="alert-success">Você está logado como: <?= usuariologado() ?></p>
else...
```

Funções auxiliares

```
 session_start();
function logausuario($email){
  $_SESSION["usuario_logado"] = $email;
}
function usuarioestalogado()
{
return (isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"]));
 }
```

Entretando ele nunca entra no **if** apenas no **else** e olhando nos cookies a session está presente la:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem ideia de por que isso ocorre?

Comment: Essas funções estão em um arquivo diferendo do if?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)` retorna o que?

Comment: @rray estão sim.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro retorna array(1) { ["usuario_logado"]=> NULL } array(1) { ["usuario_logado"]=> NULL }

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Muito estranho. Faça mais um teste: `var_dump($_SESSION, isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"]))`

Comment: Tem como mostrar um pouco mais de codigo?

Answer (score 3):

Se não me engano em comparações o PHP considera Null como Falso.
Uma das alternativas é fazer o seguinte:

```
function usuarioestalogado()
{
return isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"])) && !empty($_SESSION["usuario_logado"])  ? true : false;
 }
```